# Codeigniter Model->insert or update from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

From the CodeIgniter perspective how legit is the following code:

```
$this->admin_model->getDb()->update('users',array('Verified'=>1,'Hash'=>''),array('Hash'=>$hash));
```

This code works fine - its not an issue of erroring rather location. Should a controller be able to call an update/insert function or should this really be only accessed from a model directly? My thoughts are that the actual logic is being kept out of the controller apart from having to know the field names and table.

Comment: The issue is that you now have two places to change code if the definition changes - once in the controller and once in the model. imo, It is more useful to think of the controller as a `manager` that directs information to 'staff' that know exactly how to do their process on that information. They tell the `controller` how well they did at processing the information.

Comment: I like the point about the definition changes and having 2 places to update.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is stand for **M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller.

**Whats Model layer?**

As mostly we write Database code(insert, update, delete, select, etc...) in model. Cz this is an layer which we used only for make connection with Database.

[image: mvc]

**Can we write DB codes is controller??**

Ya. Of course you can. Only in MVC we not write DB codes in view. Other that that you can write. but *its not good*.

**The way [Codeigniter refer model](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#what-is-a-model)??**

Models are PHP classes that are designed to work with information in your database. For example, let’s say you use CodeIgniter to manage a blog. You might have a model class that contains functions to insert, update, and retrieve your blog data

Comment: @tereško what codeigniter nothing to do with mvc? Lol. 

Comment: Yes. CodeIgniter has nothing to do with MVC architectural pattern. What it calls "view" is just a template, what it calls "controller" contains all the business logic and performs rendering and validation, and what it calls "models" are table abstractions. At best it is mimicking Rails architecture.

Comment: Read this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html on their official site

Comment: Maybe you should read this instead: https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html